# Passing Multiple Generics Into Java Method

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, icomparable

Using Java. The goal is to search for a value, given as a generic, in an ArrayList, also given as a generic.

My Student class (pertinent parts)

```
public class Student<T> implements Comparable
{
    private String studName;
    private Integer gradeAverage;

    public Student(String nameIn, int gradeIn)
    {
        studName = nameIn;
        gradeAverage = gradeIn;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj)
    {
        Student s1 = (Student)obj;
        return(this.gradeAverage - s1.gradeAverage);
    }
}
```

My Search; thinking there may be a problem with the generic specifications

```
public class SearchMethods<T,S>
{
    public <T extends Comparable, S extends Comparable> void BinarySearch(T[] inputArray, S searchValue)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
        {
            T search = inputArray[i];
            if(searchValue.compareTo(search) == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(searchValue + " is at index " + i);
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if(found == false)
        {
            System.out.println(searchValue + " was not found");
        }
    }    
}
```

And my main()

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Student studentOne = new Student("James",92);
    Student studentTwo = new Student("Mary",95);
    Student studentThree = new Student("Bobbie",82);
    Student studentFour = new Student("Emily",100);
    Student studentFive = new Student("Joey",88);

    ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    studentList.add(studentOne);
    studentList.add(studentTwo);
    studentList.add(studentThree);
    studentList.add(studentFour);
    studentList.add(studentFive);

    SearchMethods<ArrayList, Student> searchMethods = new SearchMethods<ArrayList, Student>();

    searchMethods.BinarySearch(studentList, studentOne);  //Should print that it was found at index 0
```

The given compiler error states that an argument mismatch, that ArrayList cannot be converted to T#1[]. But that's the whole point of generics, right?? Interestingly, no analogous error is given for the second type, but maybe the compiler just hasn't read ahead that far.

I'm pretty sure my syntax is OK at the class level, so the error is likely with the calling objects in main(). Though, I could be wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. what is the `<T>` in Student ? 2. why are you trying to compare type `S` to type T` ? 3. [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) does *not* extend `Comparable` and last, 4. `BinarySearch` accepts an array of `T` as the first argument, not an arrayList

Comment: 1) That was trying random things to see what works.

2) I'm not trying to compare type S to type T per se, but T[] is composed of type S.

Comment: `searchValue.compareTo(search)` when you declared that `searchValue` is type `S` and `search` is type `T`

Comment: Also, `Comparable` (instead of `Comparable<T>`) is a raw type.

Comment: 1. trying "random things" won't get you far. Do what you understand and understand what you're doing. 2. "T[] is composed of type S" - I'm not sure what it means but it's probably *not* true

Comment: You probably want to replace `T[] inputArray` with `List<S>` because `studentList` is a list - not an array

Comment: T[] is an ArrayList that can be of any type. In mine, the type is the studentList. S is the type that composes them, in this case it is Student. They're generics because I want to be able to do it for any custom class.

Comment: `ArrayList` is **not** an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert arraylist to an array. Check the argument for Binary Search.

Try this:

```
  SearchMethods<ArrayList, Student> searchMethods = new SearchMethods<ArrayList, Student>();

    searchMethods.BinarySearch(studentList.toArray(new Student[studentList.size()]), studentOne);
```

You could also change BinarySearch where you work with an arraylist.

While this is not part of the question, it is important not compute the difference for compareTo or you will get overflow error.

Try this:

```
 class Student<T> implements Comparable
{
private String studName;
private Integer gradeAverage;

public Student(String nameIn, int gradeIn)
{
    studName = nameIn;
    gradeAverage = gradeIn;
}

public int compareTo(Object obj)
{
    Student s1 = (Student)obj;
    if (this.gradeAverage < s1.gradeAverage){
        return -1;
    }
    if(this.gradeAverage == s1.gradeAverage){
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "student name="+studName +" grade average= " + gradeAverage;
}
}
```

Comment: Switching ArrayList into an Array of the generic objects worked!! Thank you. I've been dying about this since Monday after work. Thanks for the compareTo tip as well. I had a toString override but didn't include because it wasn't topical, but I appreciate it nonetheless.
EDIT: works with all my other classes' test objects, too!